# First time using Dask (SGECluster) in an application

Tags: python, cluster-computing, dask

I am new to Dask so I wrote the following code as a "hello world" app. My purpose is to integrate Dask into one of my projects, for the purpose of replacing multiprocessing.

```
from dask_jobqueue import SGECluster
from dask.distributed import Client

cluster = SGECluster(
    queue="somequeue",
    cores=4,
    memory="8GB",
    job_extra=["-pe", "someenv", "4"],
    )

client = Client(cluster)
cluster.scale(jobs=1)

# Perform the computations using the Dask client

# Shut down the cluster once finished
client.close()
cluster.close()
```

The code didn't work so I started working with the interpreter. After I typed the

> cluster.scale(jobs=1)

I get the following Exception:

> Task exception was never retrieved future: <Task finished
> coro=<_wrap_awaitable() done, defined at
> /tools/python/python3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py:530>
> exception=RuntimeError('Command exited with non-zero exit code.\nExit
> code: 2\nCommand:\nqsub
> /tmp/tmpfmm9s9q1.sh\nstdout:\n\nstderr:\nUnable to read script file
> because of error: ERROR! -q option must have queue list
> argument\n\n',)> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/tools/python/python3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 537, in
> _wrap_awaitable
> return (yield from awaitable.**await**())   File "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py",
> line 71, in _
> await self.start()   File "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/core.py",
> line 325, in start
> out = await self._submit_job(fn)   File "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/core.py",
> line 308, in _submit_job
> return self._call(shlex.split(self.submit_command) + [script_filename])   File
> "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/core.py",
> line 408, in _call
> "stderr:\n{}\n".format(proc.returncode, cmd_str, out, err) RuntimeError: Command exited with non-zero exit code. Exit code: 2
> Command: qsub /tmp/tmpfmm9s9q1.sh stdout:
>
> stderr: Unable to read script file because of error: ERROR! -q option
> must have queue list argument
>
> tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback
> functools.partial(<bound method IOLoop._discard_future_result of
> <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop object at 0x7f3c24fc7710>>,
> <Task finished coro=<SpecCluster._correct_state_internal() done,
> defined at
> /home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py:325>
> exception=RuntimeError('Command exited with non-zero exit code.\nExit
> code: 2\nCommand:\nqsub
> /tmp/tmpfcsf4h_g.sh\nstdout:\n\nstderr:\nUnable to read script file
> because of error: ERROR! -q option must have queue list
> argument\n\n',)>) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py",
> line 741, in _run_callback
> ret = callback()   File "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py",
> line 765, in _discard_future_result
> future.result()   File "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py",
> line 360, in _correct_state_internal
> await w  # for tornado gen.coroutine support   File "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py",
> line 71, in _
> await self.start()   File "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/core.py",
> line 325, in start
> out = await self._submit_job(fn)   File "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/core.py",
> line 308, in _submit_job
> return self._call(shlex.split(self.submit_command) + [script_filename])   File
> "/home/moshes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/core.py",
> line 408, in _call
> "stderr:\n{}\n".format(proc.returncode, cmd_str, out, err) RuntimeError: Command exited with non-zero exit code. Exit code: 2
> Command: qsub /tmp/tmpfcsf4h_g.sh stdout:
>
> stderr: Unable to read script file because of error: ERROR! -q option
> must have queue list argument

I know that the queue name and parallel environment are correct as I managed to run the following command line and got a job with 4 slots

```
qsub -q somequeue -pe someenv 4 -l h_vmem=8G,h_rt=1:00:00 my_script.sh
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, could you check the job script generated by dask-jobqueue using print(cluster.job_script())? See https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/debug.html.